# How to fix mobile hotspot?

Tags: root-access, wifi-hotspot, sim-card, unrooting, htc-one-m8

Shortly said, my mobile hotspot doesn't work.

I can connect my laptop to my phone but I can't get on the web. Mobile data on my phone works flawlessly.

What I've tried:

- Putting my SIM card into another device
- Connecting other devices to my phone's hotspot
- Connecting my laptop to other hotspots
- Putting another SIM card into my phone

All of the above, except the second point, work.

I was thinking it's my phones fault, but the last list item confuses me.
Why does it work, when I insert another SIM card? I didn't change any settings. I even let the hotspot run and just switched SIM cards.

I already asked my mobile provider if there are any special settings, either on my phone or on my laptop, I have to make. But they don't know about anything.

Has somebody ever encountered a similar problem or has an idea what else I could try?

*I have another problem which I thought is somehow connected to the above one:*

I rooted my phone and tried to unroot it again for OTA updates. But the phone doesn't properly restart. It always boots to the bootloader and I can't get into recovery.

But since my hotspot works with a different SIM card I don't think these two problems are connected.

I think the cause of my hotspot not working is the special constellation of my phone with my SIM card.

Comment: When you connect your laptop or other devices to your hotspot, can you try setting custom DNS address there, such as 8.8.8.8?

Comment: @Firelord Thanks for the reminder. I forgot to mention that. I've already tried that as well. In Chrome it gives me a DNS error (*DNS_PROBE_FINISHED* if I remember right)but setting a custom DNS doesn't help.